# Computer is slow to startup, and asks lots of questions

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm not very good with the computer and I'm a senior so please be kind. when I try to restart my computer it says press esc for start up menu but it takes a long time for the next words which are something like ESC  Pause start up and then it finally goes to a screen with lots of choices but I can then press Enter and the computer finally starts up.  I have a virus protection so I'm not sure why this is happening. the computer is a HP Paviliondv7-6187 Entertainment pc.

I also notice that when I'm on the computer it seems to freeze for a moment when I'm clicking on something.

Can you advise what the problem is?

Please use terms so I know what to do.

Comment: Those HPs laptops have onboard NVIDIA graphics processors that are notoriously faulty. It might be about to fail with the freezing and stuff. Back up your important files. How old is it?

Comment: @Jacki could you elaborate a little more on the second problem you're facing? Does the computer turn unresponsive only when you start certain programs or does it happen all the time? Do you see popups similar to [this](http://blog.doohelp.com/blogimages/2014/08/PC-Cleaner-Pro-2014-fake-antivirus-removal1.jpg) or [this](http://www.spywarevoid.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/SpyEraser_YourComputerIsInfected.jpg) showing up randomly while using your computer?

Answer (score 1):

The escape/startup menu is optional! Just ignore it.

By default, most machines will automatically start from the default hard drive, if you however want to install/change to something else, you need to tell your machine to boot from that instead - that is what the menu is for. For a normal start up, you can just ignore it.

You have a pretty decent specification computer (from doing a quick Google search), so, it shouldn't be freezing/slow. If you have an external mouse, I would try that...

... I have seen it a few times from different laptop vendors that if you press any keyboard key, it freezes the mouse for a few seconds (to prevent mis clicking whilst typing/arms stretched across the touchpad).

You can also go to Control Panel and take a look at mouse/touch pad settings to see if you have this feature and if you can configure/change it.

It may be something else, but, we need to dig deeper in to troubleshooting and I would like to rule what I said in here out first.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** ALWAYS make sure you have backups of your important files (think photo's, e-mails, office documents etc.), especially when you experience problems. This can't be overstated.

As the previous answer says, that very first thing you can indeed safely ignore, it's just telling you how to enter the hardware configuration, should be fine as is. You can seriously hurt the performance of your system if you go in there without knowledge, so without extensive research or a professional nearby, just leave it.

> ... and then it finally goes to a screen with lots of choices but I
>   can then press Enter and the computer finally starts up ...

I'm not sure from your information, but my guess is this is the Windows "advanced startup options" menu ([info](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode#1TC=windows-7)). You can confirm this by checking that some of the choices are "Safe Mode", "Repair Your Computer", "Start Windows Normally" and a bunch more of those? (With the option to start normally highlighted by default, which is what you choose by pressing enter or just waiting?) This menu normally only appears if/when Windows had problems the last time it was started or Windows wasn't closed correctly the last time you exited.
/edit: hmm, thinking of that... How do you "close" your computer? Be sure to use the regular Windows shutdown option from the start menu, do not pull the power cord or keep the power button pressed till it dies.

Anyway, what you could try here is "Repair Your Computer" or "Last Known Good Configuration". (You can "browse" to those other options by using the arrow (cursor) keys on your keyboard.) Make sure you have your Windows 7 installation disk handy as it may ask for it.

> I also notice that when I'm on the computer it seems to freeze for a
>   moment when I'm clicking on something.

This is a very general problem that can have a myriad of causes, anything from failing RAM chips in the motherboard of your computer to the last update of your antivirus containing a bug, to configuration settings in your control panel... Anything really.

A quite general thing you can try is [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore), to restore your Windows system files and settings to a point in time before you had these issues, if ever. Try to select a point as close to, but still before, the moment the problems started. This is a very very general troubleshooting option and will tell you nothing about what is causing your trouble, but sometimes it can work wonders. Note that this will not affect any of your personal files (photo's, documents, mails etc.), just your system settings themselves, so playing with this is relatively safe. BUT: always make sure you have backups of your important files, especially when you experience problems.

Come to think of it... You wouldn't perchance have multiple "real-time" virus scanners installed? (E.g. McAfee and Avira?) This is a surefire way to REALLY slow down the computer, as some virus scanners have conflicting ways of "snatching" a file when you click it in order to scan it before it is actually executed. Normally you shouldn't notice this but two AV's can seriously disturb eachother.

Your information is very general and it's hard to be much more specific; hopefully these general answers work for you. If not, be sure to extend your answer with anything you tried/investigated and the results. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you see this:
[image: Press Esc]

every time you boot and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> brings up this:
[image: HP Startup menu]

In that case, you don't need to press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key every time the computer boots up (as @WilliamHilsum wrote). You simply need to wait for a few seconds and the message should disappear on its own and the computer will proceed with booting Windows.

Source: [HP Discussion Boards - Press ESC key for start menu](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/Press-ESC-key-for-start-menu/m-p/4473172/highlight/true#M258168)

I can't say what might be causing the other problem (computer being unresponsive for a moment after you click on something) without some more information about the problem.